# Delete an element from another list

Tags: java, list

I've an element named center. With this one, I can access to animal cages by `center.getCages()` (A Cage contains few Animal)

If I do a `.stream()` on `center.getCages()`, I can filter on cages that contain residents (`cage.getResidents()`)

And I want to delete a resident with his id that I get from the DELETE of my request.

```
<ns2:center xmlns:ns2="m1GIL:rest:tp">
    <cages>
        <capacity>25</capacity>
        <name>usa</name>
        <position>
            <latitude>49.305</latitude>
            <longitude>1.2157357</longitude>
        </position>
        <residents>
            <cage>usa</cage>
            <id>f2af5996-cc9c-4e97-9c00-3f847d533d50</id>
            <name>Tic</name>
            <species>Chipmunk</species>
        </residents>
        <residents>
            <cage>usa</cage>
            <id>c5e53e4c-7832-45bb-bd2d-3e75b5497987</id>
            <name>Tac</name>
            <species>Chipmunk</species>
        </residents>
        <residents>
            <cage>usa</cage>
            <id>53e21031-8314-47e4-a6ae-cbf8d78eb962</id>
            <name>Bob</name>
            <species>Arapaima gigas</species>
        </residents>
        <residents>
            <cage>usa</cage>
            <id>25b9723b-8cab-402c-8062-38054e3ea4d8</id>
            <name>Toto</name>
            <species>Arapaima gigas</species>
        </residents>
    </cages>
</ns2:center>
```

Thanks by advance!

EDIT :

For the moment, I did that :

```
Cage selectedCage = center
        .getCages()
        .stream()
        .filter(cage -> cage
                .getResidents()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(an -> an.getId().equals(animal_id)))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new HTTPException(404));

selectedCage
    .getResidents()
    .removeIf(an -> an.getId().equals(animal_id));
```

But It didn't work.

Second EDIT :

```
Cage selectedCage = center.getCages()
    .stream()
    .filter(cage -> cage.getResidents()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(an -> an.getId().equals(UUID.fromString(animal_id))))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new HTTPException(404));

selectedCage.getResidents().removeIf(an -> an.getId().equals(UUID.fromString(animal_id)));
```

This is working! The bug was that I did equals on a string and not on an UUID.
There is a better way to do it or it's correct ?

Comment: Hi Robert, do you have the code you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I brought an edit.

Comment: It goes in the Throw (HTTPException(404))

Comment: Then it's not the delete that doesn't work, but the way you try to find. It just means that nonematch

Comment: Yes it's true thanks. I fixed the issue.. There is a better solution for my second edit ?